# how to identify html file upload wizard closed by user without selecting file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to identify if user is closed the file upload wizard of the browser without selecting a file. Identification should be happened immediately after closing the wizard and identification must be able to be done with JavaScript. Is there any event that fires when user close the file selection wizard for upload? We can use JQuery also. I have used several events but none of them fired immediately after wizard close.

```html
<input type="file" id="fileTaker" 
               oncancel="cancelledFile()"
               onabort="abortedFile()"
               onclose="closedFile()"
               onclick="clickedFile()"
               onchange="changedFile()"
               onblur="bluredFile()"
               onemptied="emptiedFile()"
               onformchange="formChanged()"
               onsuspend="suspendFile()"
               />
```

Here onchange fires only if user select file and opened for upload (onchange fires sporadically after wizard close. but I need reliable event). onclick and onblur fires when opening the wizard. others not fired. 
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can try to check if the innerHTML of the input field has changed?

Comment: @Rick, innerHTML is not changing if user is not selected any file.

Comment: I feel that there is no any browser support for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize `change`, `blur` events at `<input type="file">` element, `focus` event at `window`; check if `<input type="file">` element `.files` property `.length` is equal to `0`

```html
<script>
  function changedFile(el, fromfocus) {
    // remove `fromfocus` to set condition
    // to `true` for both `onchange` event 
    // and direct call to `changedFile`
    // from within `window.onfocus` handler
    if (el.files.length === 0 && fromfocus) {
      console.log(el.files.length);
    }
  }
  
  function handleBlur(el) {
    window.onfocus = function() {
      this.onfocus = null;
      // pass `true` to prevent `if` statement 
      // being `true` for both `onchange` event
      // and direct call to `changedFile` here
      changedFile(el, true);
    }
  }
</script>
<input type="file" id="fileTaker" 
       onchange="changedFile(this)" 
       onblur="handleBlur(this)" />
```

Comment: Might be. Seems there is no exact event to identify wizard close.